# How to calculate total time in minuets of an event occurred many time within an hour and each hour in Msql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I am hanged in a problem may be due to my lack of expertise. I have following mysql table:

**Fdname** --  **fcode** - **timestate** - **Status**

University  104 2015-03-05 01:37:00 OFF

University  104 2015-03-05 01:42:00 ON

University  104 2015-03-05 01:55:00 OFF

University  104 2015-03-05 02:00:00 ON

University  104 2015-03-05 07:20:00 OFF

University  104 2015-03-05 07:22:00 ON

University  104 2015-03-05 10:17:00 OFF

University  104 2015-03-05 11:16:00 ON

University  104 2015-03-05 12:17:00 OFF

University  104 2015-03-05 13:17:00 ON

University  104 2015-03-05 15:19:00 OFF

University  104 2015-03-05 16:16:00 ON

University  104 2015-03-05 18:16:00 OFF

University  104 2015-03-05 20:16:00 ON

University  104 2015-03-05 21:17:00 OFF

University  104 2015-03-05 22:18:00 ON

I need to calculate cumulative total minutes for each state 'OFF' and 'ON' per clock hour. i.e. i should know how many minutes a fname remains OFF within each hour. I tried a lot in php but could find any clue. ANy body can help or suggest in terms of query or php script. I will really appreciate.

Comment: what u tried so far ?

Comment: I have tried some thing like this logic but it gives me wrong result:

while($r = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){

 if($r['status'] == 'OFF')

  {

  $time_off = strtotime($r['timestate']);

  $t = substr($r['timestate'],11,2);

  if($t == '01')

  {  

      $from_time_off = strtotime($r['timestate']);

                        $m1 += round(abs($time_on - $from_time_off) / 60,2);

  }

   }

Comment: if($r['status'] == 'ON')

  {

   $time_on = strtotime($r['timestate']);

  $t = substr($r['timestate'],11,2);

  if($t == '01')

  {

   $from_time_on = strtotime($r['timestate']);

                        $n1 += round(abs($time_off - $from_time_on) / 60,2);

  }

  }

}

Comment: Could you please mark my answer as correct with the green check if my answer solved your issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Considering that `$rs` is the result of your appropriate query, I believe this will give you the result you're looking for.

```
$ontime = NULL;
$offtime = NULL;
$totalseconds = 0;

while($r = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){ 
    if($r["status"] == "OFF"){
        $offtime = strtotime($r["timestate"]);
    }
    if($r["status"] == "ON" AND $offtime !== NULL){
        $ontime = strtotime($r["timestate"]);
        $totalseconds += $ontime - $offtime;
        $offtime=NULL;
        $ontime=NULL; 
    }
}
```

`$totalseconds` will hold your total downtime in seconds